# How do I make this javascript code cleaner and more concise? (div flashing colors)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function flash(color){
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (++count === 7) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else {
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                $('#row').css({'background-color':'white'})
            }
            else {
                $('#row').css({'background-color':color})
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

It's supposed to flash 3 times (one second on, one second off). Any way to make this more concise? Also the 'white' just means there is no color, so maybe it would be better to use none? Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to have a working snippet with some HTML, don't you think? :)

Comment: You could do this using CSS keyframes if you preferred, that would clean up the JS code to zero :) It just depends on whether the colours shown are static or dynamic

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The one thing that I think might not work with CSS keyframes is that you still have to add logic to remove or apply the class that carries the animation.  If you know of a good way to that without JS, I'd love to get feedback about it on my answer.

Comment: @zero298 you don't need to change the class at all, you set the keyframes to have the background colour at a given % progress of the total animation, and set it to only repeat once

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But what if you want to flash again later?

Comment: Then you'd need some JS code to remove/add the class again, but that's not what the OPs brief states

Answer (score 1):

*I love me some ES6.*

```
const flash = color => {
  let count = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (++count === 7) clearInterval(interval);
    else $('#row').css('background-color', count % 2 ? color : 'white');
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `const interval`? Btw, `function flash(color) {` is in fact more concise :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yep, intervals and timeouts should always be a `const`, my bad ^^. I'd rather keep the lambda declaration though, if feels so much cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

"Clean" and "concise" are subjective terms to some degree, and I differ with the other answer in equating them to "fewest lines".

In this case, I would recommend identifying what changes you want to make according to the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself. The method for creating DRY code has been called "semantic compression", and we can apply it here.

First, look for the parts of your code that you are reusing. There is only one part, which is the beginning of your jquery lines: `$('#row').css({'background-color':`. This identifies the parts of the code that we can clean up. There is a simple way to avoid repeating this statement:

```
function flash(color){
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (++count === 7) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else {
            var new_color = color;
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                new_color = 'white';
            }
            $('#row').css({'background-color':new_color});
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Here, you've compressed both of the jquery lines into just one, and left one as an assignment to color, which is the only line of its kind in your code. Scanning again for repeated parts, you can see that there is no operation that you are performing more than once. You can then strip the braces, use the ES6 syntax, use ternaries to cram your conditionals onto one line, or any sort of preference, but it's up to interpretation whether that is cleaner or more concise. In my opinion, it will simply reduce readability, and you can see whether you are Repeating Yourself, and if not, you are at a clean and concise piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) instead that way your actual animation logic is segregated to your styling code (your CSS) and the logic to apply animations is modularized to it's own place as well:

```js
function animationEndCallback(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove(e.animationName);
  e.target.removeEventListener("animationend", animationEndCallback);
}

function cleanAnimation(el, animation) {
  el.addEventListener("animationend", animationEndCallback);
  el.classList.add(animation);
}

const toBeFlashed = document.getElementById("el");
const btn = document.getElementById("flasher");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cleanAnimation(toBeFlashed, "flashy");
});
```

```css
@keyframes flashy {
  from {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  to {
    background-color: rgb(116, 195, 224);
  }
}

.flashy {
  animation: 1s flashy 4 alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="el">Hello</div>
<button id="flasher" type="button">Flash</button>
```